# Commerce product price based on selected value of Webform component

Tags: commerce, webforms

I am using: Drupal: 7-4.1 [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform): 7.x-4.12 [Webform Commerce intg](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_webform): 7.x-2.0 Beta1 [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) 7.x 1.11

I have created a Commerce Webform to order commerce products. I am trying to set a rule in "Product pricing rules" where:

If the user chooses a specific value in a Webform component, I would like to increase the price of the product chosen.

> Example: I have a webform that shows 3 table products, if the user
>   choses table 1, of which the base price is 20 GBP, the next step in
>   the form is for the user to chose if they want it installed by an
>   expert, if the users choses Yes, I would like that the base price
>   changes to 40 GBP.

I would like someone to help me setup a rule to make the product price change based on the webform component value. The new price should be seen at the webform preview (before submission) or if that is not possible, then when the product reaches the cart.

Comment: I have managed to find the event: Calculate sell price, and the condition (php: if ($data['components']['timeframe']['value'][0]=='tid_138') {return TRUE;} else {return FALSE;})
but I cant seem to access the commerce product sell price when I add the Action: multiply price...please help